# Does antibody staining / immunolabeling block or inhibit protein function?

Tags: antibody, experimental-design, protein-binding, research-process, research-tools

In dissociated live cells, does staining them with an antibody block the protein's function?

I am sorting cells based on their expression of a few marker genes, and culturing them post-sort for several days.

How can one assess if the protein is still functional?

Comment: That depends on a number of factors: The actual place where the antibody binds, the protein itself and also the number of available protein molecules. About which protein are you thinking?

Comment: Also, the assay for functionality completely depends on the protein you're testing. Assuming you have an in vitro assay for your protein's function, you could try performing the assay at a given protein concentration with varying concentration of antibody to see if there is a significant effect on activity *in vitro.* It might not correlate well *in vivo,* but it is a start.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Chris. I do not have a specific protein in mind; rather I have a panel of proteins which I want to use to sort cells based on their expression, and I am worried that these antibodies will mess with the cell's behavior, as I will continue to observe them after selecting for them.

Comment: Thanks, @A.Kennard. That makes sense, although I don't have an in vitro assay for my proteins' functions. Do you know of any examples where people have verified the activity of proteins for which they added antibodies in vivo?